# How does echo actually work in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, echo

When I type any key, normally, it is immediately echoed back to the std output i.e.my screen.

If I have to enter a password, that says that it will not echo back, I cannot see the keys that I type.

How does this work.

Does each key press go to the kernel immediately(without me pressing ENTER), and then the kernel decides to echo them or not? 
Like , I press 'A', it goes to the kernel; kernel echoes it; I get it on my screen. Now I hit 'B'...same sequence again...; Now I have 'AB' on my screen (my command) and hit ENTER; My command goes to the kernel and is finally executed.

Is there any other explanation? What happens in the background during the key presses?

Comment: your commands are interpreted by shell,not kernel.

Comment: Conflating stdout and your screen is a mistake.  stdout is not your screen.  stdin is not your keyboard.  Sometimes, the stdout stream of a process is associated with a screen.  Sometimes, stdin is associated with a keyboard.  But they are NOT the same.  Stop thinking that they are.

Comment: @Reddy. Yes. I know commands are interpreted by the shell. I was talking about keystrokes.

Comment: @Pursel. Thats why I have written "i.e.my screen.", as stdout could have also been a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminal driver in the kernel can be put in several modes (there are actually many more flags than this, and these days "cbreak" is actually the opposite of a different flag, so this is simplified).

The "cbreak" mode means that the process that is attempting to read from the terminal will receive keyboard input as soon as it is available. When cbreak mode is off, the data is stored by the kernel in a buffer until enter is pressed, and certain keys like backspace are handled by the kernel (when you press backspace, it removes the character from the buffer and - if echo mode is on - writes "backspace-space-backspace" to the terminal to overwrite the character with a blank space).

Echo mode means that whenever the user presses a key, the kernel will immediately echo it back to the screen. When it is off, nothing will be echoed to the screen, and the program will need to write it to the terminal if it wants you to see it.

There are several typical situations:

- In programs that do advanced input handling (like most shells, or something like a full screen program), cbreak is on and echo is off; the program will write the character to the terminal itself if it is not part of a special key escape sequence.
- In most situations [the default with a simple program that reads stdin and writes stdout], echo is on and cbreak is off. When you type, it behaves as I described above, all of this is handled by the kernel until you hit enter and it sends it to the application. Input editing is limited to backspace [and ctrl-u, ctrl-w], trying to use the arrow keys will just put escape sequences like `^[[D` in the input line.
- When reading a password, echo is off and cbreak is off. Input works just like the default case, except the kernel does not copy input to the screen.

The program that is running tells the kernel what mode to have it in with the `termios` functions. You can use the `stty` command to do the same in a shell environment, but be aware that this may interfere with the shell's own input handling or with what programs you run expect the default state to be.

Comment: if echo mode is on - writes "backspace-space-backspace": Could you explain this please? Why not a simple "backspace" echo to the terminal. Isn't the extra "space-backspace" futile?

Comment: @dams Printing a backspace just moves the cursor left, it doesn't erase the character.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard generates electrical signals that are eventually interpreted as keycodes that correspond to letters - 'A', 'B', function keys F1, F2 etc. This all happen in the keyboard driver that is handled by the kernel. That keyboard driver has a buffer to receive all the keypresses from the keyboard and sends that to the kernel that in turn direct them to processes that is currently having the focus. What to do with the sequence of keys are totally decided by the individual application, such as whether to display the keys or not.

Answer (score -1):

`echo` program is part of `coreutils`. You can download its sources [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/). Look at `src/echo.c` it's quite small. You can see that `echo` uses `fputc` or `putchar` calls. Those calls deal with standard stream called `stdout`. The architecture of standard streams is quite complicated and it's beyond of this post. You can found it using for example `google`.

Comment: Ah, I missed smthng. Forgive me